# How to get the generated key for a column with lowercase characters from Oracle using JdbcTemplate (or plain JDBC)

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jdbctemplate, id-generation

If I create a table like this:

```sql
create table standard (
    id NUMBER GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    text varchar2(200)
)
```

I can insert some data and get the generated id back with a method like this:

```java
Object insertAndReturnStandardId() {

    GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    template.update("insert into standard (text) values('test text')",new MapSqlParameterSource(), keyHolder, new String[]{"id"});

    return  keyHolder.getKey();
}
```

`template` here is a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, but since there are no parameters it should be equivalent to a similar call to `JdbcTemplate`.

But if I use a slightly different table with a lower case column name for the id:

```sql
create table lowercase (
    "id" NUMBER GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    text varchar2(200)
)
```

Passing the column name `id` fails:

```
Object insertAndReturnLowerCaseId() {
    GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    template.update("insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')",new MapSqlParameterSource(), keyHolder, new String[]{"id"});

    return  keyHolder.getKey();
}
```

With (full call stack below)

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier
```

Passing the column name quoted `"id"` fails as well:

```
private Object insertAndReturnLowerCaseId() {
    GeneratedKeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    template.update("insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')",new MapSqlParameterSource(), keyHolder, new String[]{"\"id\""});

    return  keyHolder.getKey();
}
```

With (full call stack below)

```
PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17068]; Invalid argument(s) in call; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
```

So: How do I get the generated value from an Oracle database when the id column is lower case?
A solution based on the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` or the `JdbcTemplate` are preferred, but I take an answer based on plain JDBC just as well.

#### Full call stack when id IS NOT quoted in call to update

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:893) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:349) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at de.schauderhaft.dbtestclient.DbtestclientApplication.insertAndReturnLowerCaseId(DbtestclientApplication.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.schauderhaft.dbtestclient.DbtestclientApplication.run(DbtestclientApplication.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:970) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3756) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3736) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1063) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$1(JdbcTemplate.java:894) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

#### Full call stack when id IS quoted in call to update

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [insert into lowercase (text) values('test text')]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17068]; Invalid argument(s) in call; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:893) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:349) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at de.schauderhaft.dbtestclient.DbtestclientApplication.insertAndReturnLowerCaseId(DbtestclientApplication.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.schauderhaft.dbtestclient.DbtestclientApplication.run(DbtestclientApplication.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.AutoKeyInfo.getNewSql(AutoKeyInfo.java:189) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.prepareStatement(PhysicalConnection.java:4656) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreatorFactory$PreparedStatementCreatorImpl.createPreparedStatement(PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.java:230) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:615) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What if you pass: new String[]{"\"id\""}

Comment: Not something I use, but from the docs, does [`setResultsMapCaseInsensitive()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#setResultsMapCaseInsensitive-boolean-) affect what you see? (If it does and is set to true, your original query will then fail, presumably...)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli that's what I do in the second attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in 21c, the Oracle JDBC thin driver supports double-quoted generated keys. The code snippet below works with the 21c and 23c drivers. With 19c it gives an error (`Invalid argument(s) in call`). Note that the `lowercase` table is the same as the one mentioned in the question.

```java
String QUERY = "INSERT INTO lowercase (text) VALUES (?)";
try (PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY, new String[] { "\"id\"" })) {
    statement.setString(1, "Foo");
    int affectedRows = statement.executeUpdate();
    assert (affectedRows==1);
    try (ResultSet keys = statement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
       assert(keys.next());
       System.out.println("keys.getLong(1)="+keys.getLong(1));
    }
      // omitted
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a JDBC driver bug SR 3-18090632291. Some info an be found here:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7962
- https://twitter.com/AFulgens/status/1227148982259982337

This is really difficult to work around, because the JDBC driver tampers with the SQL string, and you cannot really do anything about that.

Comment: Isn't it a joy that each JDBC driver messes around with the actual SQL?</sarcasm>

Comment: @mp911de: This is "just" a bug... The intention is reasonable. Behind the scenes, some PL/SQL is generated to be able to fetch generated values. Most JDBC users probably don't want to do that manually...